# Extraction of sublists from a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list consisting of strings and numbers, from which I need to extract sublists.

```
lis = {k, a, b, cf, e, 1, c, d, 2, z, d, 3, f, g, z, h, a, q, r, 4, s, 5, z, j, a}
```

The sublists I need are defined as a sequence of four elements bracketed by "a" and "z", and with adjacent string elements joined to each other:

```
{a, b, cf, e, 1, c, d, 2, z}  -> {bcfe, 1, cd, 2}
```

So the desired result is:

```
res = {{bcfe, 1, cd, 2}, {qr, 4, s, 5}}
```

Thanks for suggestions!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"];

lis = {k, a, b, cf, e, 1, c, d, 2, z, d, 3, f, g, z, h, a, q, r, 4, 
   s, 5, z, j, a};
```

Your `lis` does not contain any strings

```
Head /@ lis // Union

(* {Integer, Symbol} *)

DeleteCases[
  lis //. 
   {s___, a, mid___, z, e___} :> {s, SplitBy[{mid}, ! IntegerQ[#] &], 
     e}, _?AtomQ, 1] /. {{i_Integer} :> i, 
  sym : {_Symbol ..} :> StringJoin[ToString /@ sym]}

(* {{"bcfe", 1, "cd", 2}, {"qr", 4, "s", 5}} *)
```

**EDIT:** If the list has strings instead of symbols,

```
lis = {"k", "a", "b", "cf", "e", 1, "c", "d", 2, "z", "d", 3, "f", "g", "z", 
   "h", "a", "q", "r", 4, "s", 5, "z", "j", "a"};

DeleteCases[
  lis //. {s___, "a", mid___, "z", e___} :> 
     {s, SplitBy[{mid}, ! IntegerQ[#] &], e}, _?AtomQ, 1] /. 
      {{i_Integer} :> i, 
       str : {_String ..} :> StringJoin[str]}

(* {{"bcfe", 1, "cd", 2}, {"qr", 4, "s", 5}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks Bob for the reply.  My error.  I meant strings, not symbols in lis = {"k", "a", "b", "cf", "e", 1, "c", "d", 2, "z", "d", 3, "f", 
   "g", "z", "h", "a", "q", "r", 4, "s", 5, "z", "j", "a"}; a revision of your solution would be welcome.

Answer (score 6):

```
ClearAll[reShape]
reShape[a_, z_] :=  SequenceCases[#, {a, x : Except[a | z] .., z} :> 
    SequenceReplace[{x}, {s__String} :> StringJoin @ s]] &
```

***Example:***

```
lis = {"k", "a", "b", "cf", "e", 1, "c", "d", 2, "z", "d", 3, "f", 
   "g", "z", "h", "a", "q", "r", 4, "s", 5, "z", "j", "a"};

reShape["a", "z"] @ lis
```

> ```
> {{"bcfe", 1, "cd", 2}, {"qr", 4, "s", 5}}
> ```

Answer (score 5):

```
blist = {"k", "a", "b", "cf", "e", 1, "c", "d", 2, "z", "d", 3, "f", 
   "g", "z", "h", "a", "q", "r", 4, "s", 5, "z", "j", "a"};
```

Define three polymorphic functions with `Symbol`, `Integer`, `String` arguments for list catenation.

```
Clear[f]
f[k_List /; AllTrue[k, Head[#] == Symbol &]] := 
 StringJoin @@ ToString /@ k
f[k_List /; AllTrue[k, IntegerQ]] := k
f[k_List /; 
   AllTrue[StringJoin @@ Join @@ Characters /@ k, 
    MemberQ[Alphabet[]] &]] := StringJoin @@ Join @@ Characters /@ k
```

Using `SequenceCases`:

```
Map[Flatten, #, {-3}] &@
     Map[f, #, {-2}] &@
   SplitBy[#, IntegerQ] & /@
 SequenceCases[blist
  , {"a", k : Except["z"] .., "z"} :> {k}]
```

> `{{"bcfe", 1, "cd", 2}, {"qr", 4, "s", 5}}`

Answer (score 5):

```
lis = {"k", "a", "b", "cf", "e", 1, "c", "d",
   2, "z", "d", 3, "f", "g", "z", "h", "a",
   "q", "r", 4, "s", 5, "z", "j", "a"};

{ap, zp} = Flatten[Position[lis, #]] & /@ {"a", "z"}

sel = DeleteDuplicatesBy[DeleteCases[Function[av, {av + 1,
       SelectFirst[zp, # > av &, 0] - 1}] /@ ap, {_, -1}], Last];

Map[Take[lis, #] &, sel] //.
 {h___, i_String, j_String, k___} :> {h, i <> j, k}
```

> {{"bcfe", 1, "cd", 2}, {"qr", 4, "s", 5}}

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {k, a, b, cf, e, 1, c, d, 2, z, d, 3, f, g, z, h, a, q, r, 4, s, 5, z, j, a};

res = {{bcfe, 1, cd, 2}, {qr, 4, s, 5}};
```

Using `SequenceReplace`, `SequenceCases` and `LetterQ`

```
ToExpression /@ SequenceReplace[#, {s__?LetterQ} :> StringJoin[s]] & /@
 SequenceCases[list, {a, p : Except[z] .., z} :> (ToString /@ {p})]
```

> {{bcfe, 1, cd, 2}, {qr, 4, s, 5}}

```
% == res
```

> True

Answer (score 1):

```
lis = {k, a, b, cf, e, 1, c, d, 2, z, d, 3, f, g, z, h, a, q, r, 4, s, 5, z, j, a};
```

---

Grabbing the @eldo's pattern and using `SequenceSplit`:

```
 With[{l = ToString /@ lis, patt = {"a", Except["z"] .., "z"}},
 ss = Select[SequenceSplit[l, s : patt :> s], #[[1]] === "a" &];
 seqs = ss[[All, 2 ;; -2]] /. x_?VectorQ :> SplitBy[x, LetterQ];
 Map[ToExpression@*StringJoin, seqs, {2}]]
```

*Result*:

> `{{bcfe, 1, cd, 2}, {qr, 4, s, 5}}`